# CTR_DRBG versus OFB_DRBG

Tags: ctr, random-number-generator, ofb

As far as I know, in the development of ANSI X9.82, there was consideration of OFB_DRBG, a pseudorandom number generator based on block ciphers like CTR_DRBG, but it appears to have been rejected of left out of the final publication, much like MS_DRBG. Is CTR_DRBG safer than OFB_DRBG? If so, is this because OFB_DRBG would be susceptible to a known-plaintext attack?

Comment: It is because OFB has short cycles and can't be computed in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

No OFB_DRBG isn't directly vulnerable to attacks.

However from a theoretical standpoint there is one point speaking against it and in favor of CTR_DRBG.

Speed. CTR can be parallelized (can encrypt counters in parallel), OFB can't (encrypting state over and over again)

So the main reason is speed I'd guess and of course adding OFB_DRBG wouldn't have added anything to the portfolio, as CTR does the same job, but better.

Comment: Average cycle length of AES-OFB is expected to be $2^{127}$, too big to matter in practice.

Comment: oops, but at least expected collision should be around $2^{64}$ blocks for both. Just re-checked my handbook and saw that only n-bit OFB (n<blocksize) is vulnerable and not  standard OFB

Comment: Since AES is a  pseudo-random-permutation not a pseudo-random-function, you can't apply the birthday problem and the average cycle length is $2^{127}$ not $2^{64}$.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks, I remembered counter mode having an issue with birthday paradox, but I can't find the warning in my handbook, so you're likely right. But one gets problem if using 127-bit-OFB (or smaller).